# Javascript calculate image size, after image load

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, onload, wait

```
function loader(img) {
        var imgH = img.height;
        var imgW = img.width;
        console.log(imgH, imgW);    
    };

img = new Image();
img.src ='../images/pic1.jpeg';
img.onLoad = loader(img);
```

So, It is exepeted, that I'll get image's size, but I got "0 0" in console. And size of image is 500X700. What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 3):

This makes no sense:

```
img.onLoad = loader(img);
```

you want to pass the actual function to the event:

```
img.onload = loader;
```

and use `this` instead of `img` within the function.

Also you need to assign the event *before* changing the image's `src` property.

Also note that there are numerous problems with the load event on images. From the [jQuery manual on load():](http://api.jquery.com/load-event)

> Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load() shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with this that should be noted. These are:
>
> - It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function loader(){
    var imgH = this.height;
    var imgW = this.width;
    console.log(imgH, imgW); 
}
var img = new Image();
img.onload = loader;
img.src ='../images/pic1.jpeg';
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this way:

```
img.onload = function(){//here wrote everything from loader};
```

And it was the only working solution I have found.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way is to let the computer do the scaling first.

and declaring the onload = "some_function()" in the body.

```
<body onload="some_function()">
```

and then getting the sizing afterward in the script.

```
some_function(){

var image1 = document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0];
var computedStyle_image1 = window.getComputedStyle(image1);
var image_width = computedStyle_image1.getPropertyValue('width');

}
```

I noticed with google chrome you need to make sure you call the onload="function" within the body div otherwise the image values arn't set and it pulls in 0px for width and height.