# Elements disappear when refresh

Tags: html, css, refresh, element

I'm having a great trouble with something. I made this website http://arnmusica.netai.net/ (Thats a current free testing domain) and when I click on "Productos" Tab, sometimes the elements (guitars) dont show, and sometimes they do. I don't know why this keeps happening. I tried to correct or modify lots of stuff of the css, html, and didn't work. The elements appear randomly when I refresh the page. The guitars should always be visible.

Please please please help me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please make a improvement of this answer. Currently, this answer can not be useful in the future.

Comment: Wedney could you help me please?

Comment: Fiddle of your problem: https://jsfiddle.net/L74mjh2r/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please isolate your problem into a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or anything similar , so your answer can be useful in the future.

The width of the `#scroller` element is being overwritten by a misterious javascript plugin (simplyScroll.js).

The most common cause is: 
The plugin is running before the load of the images.

See [Javascript calculate image size, after image load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267663/javascript-calculate-image-size-after-image-load)

**EDIT:**

From [jQuery simple scroll website](http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/#comments):

> Notes/issues:
>
> simplyScroll jumping? Make sure you specify images sizes or start on
>   window load (Chrome is especially affected by this - it's just so darn
>   fast!)
>   http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/#comments

**EDIT2:**

You can do on `load`, but has some [caveats](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/#entry-longdesc).

```
$( '.img img' ).load(function() {  
    $("#scroller").simplyScroll({
        auto: false,
        speed: 10
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Wédney. Thanks a lot. I'm sorry I didn't post the question properly. I'm new at stackoverflow and kind of newbie at html. I promise I'll improve!

Comment: The simplyscroll.js is to make the horizontal scrolling at "productos.html" while mouse over. I just tried to change the plugin position to the end of the html document, and still couldn't fix it... Any clue?

Comment: See my edit. You need to make sure you specify images sizes.

Comment: I'm  sorry, I can see you found the answer to my problem, still I'm not quite sure how to fix it. Where should I specify the image sizes? (and what do you mean by starting on a window load)? Forgive me for all the questions, as I said I'm quite new at this... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Something like `<img src="../img/gr11.png" style="width: 192px; height: 227px;">`

Comment: Just did that on every image and had no luck :( . Maybe the problem is in other part of the code. Its quite a mess, i know. So how about if I try starting on a window load? Could you give me a hand with that?

Comment: What should I type as my function? I'm going a crazy with this =(

Comment: Hey Wédney! Had to step out from the computer. I'll be back in a couple hours and try the onload. Thanks a lot